# Почему экранируется кавычка в сырой (raw) строке?

Tags: python, строки, синтаксис

Столкнулся с сырыми строками и решил проверить их работу на простом примере.

Пожалел.

```
print(r"\")
```

Результат:

```
  File "main.py", line 1
    print(r"\")
              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Как можно понять, последняя кавычка считается спецсимволом из-за слэша.

Как такое может быть в сырой строке? В них ничего не экранируется слэшами, но почему с кавычкой это происходит?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, теперь ясно. Во многих источниках прочитал про необработанные строки, но нигде об этом исключении не говорилось. Пишут, что обратный слэш в сырых строках ничего не экранирует, я и подумал, что во всех случаях.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Вырезка из Python 3 FAQ (на английском):

### [Why can’t raw strings (r-strings) end with a backslash?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash)

> More precisely, they can’t end with an odd number of backslashes: the
> unpaired backslash at the end escapes the closing quote character,
> leaving an unterminated string.
>
> Raw strings were designed to ease creating input for processors
> (chiefly regular expression engines) that want to do their own
> backslash escape processing. Such processors consider an unmatched
> trailing backslash to be an error anyway, so raw strings disallow
> that. In return, they allow you to pass on the string quote character
> by escaping it with a backslash. These rules work well when r-strings
> are used for their intended purpose.
>
> If you’re trying to build Windows pathnames, note that all Windows
> system calls accept forward slashes too:
>
> ```
> f = open("/mydir/file.txt")  # works fine!
> ```
>
> If you’re trying to build a pathname for a DOS command, try e.g. one of
>
> ```
> dir = r"\this\is\my\dos\dir" "\\"
> dir = r"\this\is\my\dos\dir\ "[:-1]
> dir = "\\this\\is\\my\\dos\\dir\\"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

что-то вы путаете - сами подумайте как питон должен понять, что строка закончилась или не закончилась

```
"\""
'"'
"'"
'\''
```

Comment: А что трудного? Попалась кавычка - значит строка кончилась, вот и всё.